# How do $.prevAll([selector]) and $.nextAll([selector]) work?

Tags: jquery, algorithm, jquery-selectors

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out the logic behind (and replicate in plain JS) jQuery's `.prevAll()` and `.nextAll()`. Looking at the source code didn't help as much as I'd hoped.

It is important to keep in mind that prevNodes could be nested inside other elements as well. So it's not a matter of selecting siblings.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
// args should be two selectors, source node and previous nodes
const prevAll = (...args) => {
  // select all the nodes that matches the two selectors
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(args.join(', '));
  elements = Array.from(elements);

  // get index of the source node inside all elements
  const index = elements.indexOf(document.querySelector(args[0]));

  // return everything before that index
  if (index >= 0)
    return elements.slice(0, index);

  return [];
}

const prevNodes = prevAll('.start-node', '.prev-node')
```

**Test**

```js
// args should be two selectors, source node and previous nodes
const prevAll = (...args) => {
  // select all the nodes that matches the two selectors
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(args.join(', '));
  elements = Array.from(elements);

  // get index of the source node inside all elements
  const index = elements.indexOf(document.querySelector(args[0]));

  // return everything before that index
  if (index >= 0)
    return elements.slice(0, index);

  return [];
}

const prevNodes = prevAll('.start-node', '.prev-node')

console.log(prevNodes)
```

```html
<div class="prev-node"></div>
<div class="prev-node"></div>
<div class="prev-node"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="prev-node"></div> <!-- this will be included as well -->
</div>

<!-- start here -->
<div class="start-node"></div>

<div class="next-node"></div>
```

This is obviously not the perfect solution for a lot of reasons. I believe that the start-node selector should be a single, unique node. Otherwise this won't work as expected. I could pass the first argument as true Element object, but then the logic would be way more complicated.

Any other ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: In .prevAll(), try to get siblings and until the index reaches the selector, add them to array. nextAll() should skip until and including the selector, then add the remaining to array.

Comment: Thanks @TahaPaksu, I don't think this approach will work with nested nodes. Meaning, that prev-node doesn't always have to be a sibling of the start-node

Answer (score 1):

This is only `prevAll()` but it should be obvious how to go the other way (`.nextElementSibling`) :)

```js
let prevAll = (selector, restrictionSelector = "") => {
  let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)),
    restrictedElements = restrictionSelector ? Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(restrictionSelector)) : [],
    result = [];

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    let prevElement = element.previousElementSibling;

    while (prevElement) {
      if (restrictedElements.length === 0 || restrictedElements.some((r) => r === prevElement)) {
        result.push(prevElement);
      }
      prevElement = prevElement.previousElementSibling;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

let test = prevAll("div.start-node");
console.log(test);

test = prevAll("div.start-node", "div.wrapper");
console.log(test);
```

```html
<div class="prev-node"></div>
<div class="prev-node"></div>
<div class="prev-node"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="prev-node"></div>
</div>

<!-- start here -->
<div class="start-node"></div>

<div class="next-node"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I can think of in pure JS to replicate the prevAll function would be to find the current element by selector, select the first parent of that element and loop through the child elements pulling only the child nodes that have the same node name as the element you selected.

Example (this is very rough and does not follow your need for multiple arguments, you will also run in to trouble with it if you have a selector with multiple results):

```
function prevAll(selector) {
    elements = document.querySelector(selector);
    var nodeType = elements.nodeName;
    var totalElements = elements.parentElement.childNodes;
    var re = [];
    for(i = 0; i < totalElements.length; i++) {
        if(totalElements[i].nodeName != nodeType) {
            continue;
        }    
        if(totalElements[i] == elements) {
            break;
        } else {
            re[re.length] = totalElements[i];
        }
    }
    return re;
}
```

The biggest problem is that jQuery can handle an array return of elements and can apply methods to that array successfully, JS is primarily properties and doesn't support arrays of elements in adjusting that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same requirement to use prevAll and nextAll without jQuery.
This is how i did it:

```
function prevAll(element, result) {
  if(element.previousElementSibling){
    result.push(element.previousElementSibling);
    element=element.previousElementSibling;
    prevAll(element, result);
  }
  return result;
}

function nextAll(element, result) {
  if(element.nextElementSibling{
    result.push(element.nextElementSibling);
    element=element.nextElementSibling;
    nextAll(element,result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The Call:

```
    var element=document.querySelector('.class-name');//element has to be any dom element
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(prevAll(element, []), function (el) {
        //Do what you need to do with the previous elements here
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nextAll(element, []), function (el) {
        //Do what you need to do with the next elements here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my recent project:

```
const nextAll = (element) => {
    let siblingElements = []
    let elem = document.querySelector(element)

    while (elem.nextElementSibling) {
        siblingElements.push(elem.nextElementSibling)
        elem = elem.nextElementSibling
    }

    return siblingElements
 }
```

To call:

```
 nextAll('.layer')
```